# How to paste formatted text in textbox, C#

Tags: c#, textbox, paste

am trying to paste some emails into a large textbox with a semi-colon(;) at the end of each email but i don't want the semi-colon to be at the back of the last email. Please how can i go about this, all answers would be welcomed.

Comment: uhm... press Backspace if it happens? Which part of your problem is using C#? Do you have any code?

Comment: I recommend you add the ';' at the end of each email and after the loop just truncate the last character off.

Comment: What do you mean by "paste"? Do you do this in code? Do you use CTRL+V to do it? This question is unclear. Also: What does all this have to do with "formatted text" as stated in the question's title?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `TrimEnd()` function

```
string Emails = "me@email.com;metoo@email.com;";
this.textBox1.Text = Emails.TrimEnd(';');
```

or if it's already in your TextBox

`this.textBox1.Text = this.textBox1.Text.TrimEnd(';');`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string email = "metoo@email.com;abc@email.com;xyz@email.com;";
this.textBox1.text = email.Replace(";", string.Empty);
//to show emails in separate lines then use it in this way
this.textBox1.text = email.TrimEnd(';').Replace(";", Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the last char. You can do that with a substring.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what do you want. But maybe this code can help you to remove the last semi-colon if it exists.

```
var str = "email@email.com;email2@email.com;email3@email.com;";
var length = str.Length - 1;

if (str.LastIndexOf(';') == length)
{
    str.Remove(length);
}
```